# Connect AWS Dax Client to localstack DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, localstack, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I am attempting to use the AWS DaxClient to connect to a localstack setup running DynamoDB.

I start localstack from the docker-compose file in their github repo [here](https://github.com/localstack/localstack).

Then I try creating a Dax Client in Java code and pointing it to that

```
public class PlainJavaClass {


    static AmazonDynamoDB daxClient;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        AmazonDaxClientBuilder daxClientBuilder = AmazonDaxClientBuilder.standard();
        daxClientBuilder.withRegion("us-east-1").withEndpointConfiguration("localhost:4566");
        daxClient = daxClientBuilder.build();

    }
}
```

However I'm getting the following exception:

```
12:36:53.713 [main] WARN com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ClusterDaxClient - exception starting up cluster client: java.io.IOException: failed to configure cluster endpoints from hosts: [localhost:4566]
java.io.IOException: failed to configure cluster endpoints from hosts: [localhost:4566]
    at com.amazon.dax.client.cluster.Source$AutoconfSource.pull(Source.java:127)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.cluster.Source$AutoconfSource.update(Source.java:59)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.cluster.Source$AutoconfSource.refresh(Source.java:50)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.cluster.Cluster.refresh(Cluster.java:426)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.cluster.Cluster.refresh(Cluster.java:409)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.cluster.Cluster.startup(Cluster.java:330)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.cluster.Cluster.startup(Cluster.java:263)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ClusterDaxClient.<init>(ClusterDaxClient.java:148)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ClusterDaxClient.<init>(ClusterDaxClient.java:119)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.AmazonDaxClientBuilder.build(AmazonDaxClientBuilder.java:34)
    at com.example.crudspringbootdynamodb.PlainJavaClass.createDaxClient(PlainJavaClass.java:30)
    at com.example.crudspringbootdynamodb.PlainJavaClass.main(PlainJavaClass.java:50)
Caused by: com.amazon.cbor.EndOfStreamException: null
    at com.amazon.cbor.CborInputStream.readObject(CborInputStream.java:1340)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.exceptions.DaxServiceException.pickException(DaxServiceException.java:44)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.generated.DaxClientStubs.handleResponse(DaxClientStubs.java:963)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.generated.DaxClientStubs.endpoints_455855874_1(DaxClientStubs.java:479)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.DaxClient.endpoints(DaxClient.java:2375)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.cluster.Source$AutoconfSource.pullFrom(Source.java:137)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.cluster.Source$AutoconfSource.pull(Source.java:105)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: com.amazon.cbor.EndOfStreamException: null
        ... 18 common frames omitted
```

I know I'm able to connect to localstack using a normal DynamoDb client created like this:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:4566/", "us-east-1"))
                .build();
```

So not really sure where to go next. Is it possible to use DAX client to connect to DynamoDB localstack?

Comment: Did you connect to your AWS Client VPN or whatever VPN allows you to access resources in your VPC?

Comment: This is related to local stack - mocking DAX not accessing the actual DAX resource

Answer (score 2):

No, localstack does not support it yet. There is an open issue about it on github (https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/3707).